# Convert doc file to PDF

Tags: c#, .net, pdf-generation, console-application

I want to convert .doc or .docx file to .pdf Format,
 I was able to do this by using Microsoft Interop services in C#.Net .
 But i want to achieve this without using interop .dll.
I am trying to build a .exe which will convert word files to pdf. even if Office is not installed in that system. 
Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Print to PDF... how do you expect the system to read a DOC or DOCX file without Office installed?

Answer (score 0):

You could look at [JODConverter](http://artofsolving.com/opensource/jodconverter) or [Docmosis](http://www.docmosis.com) as another option though I don't think either is has a direct c# local-host-interface.  If you need to run the conversion on your own hosts you would need to use these tools through a command-line interface.  If you can use the web, Docmosis has a web-service with C# sample code.